# Any perl standard library to check if a string contains a given substring

Tags: string, perl, standard-library

Given a query, I would like to check if this contains a given substring (can contain more than one word) . But I don't want exhaustive search, because this substring can only start a fresh word.

Any perl standard libraries for this, so that I get something efficient and don't have to reinvent the wheel?

Thanks,

Comment: +1 for asking of there are modules for regexes in perl. ;)

Comment: If you are asking for very a efficient solution, you should post some example input and matching, and some constraints, such as how far into the string you should search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the perfect job for [regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html):

```
if($string =~ m/your substring/) { 
    say "substring found"; 
} else { 
    say "nothing found"; 
}
```

Comment: There's also the `can only start a fresh word` condition, which is where the `\b` metacharacter is useful to mark a word boundary.

Comment: The \b doesn't start at a fresh word, though. You're mixing up Perl's idea of a boundary with what most of the world thinks a word is.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you'll find builtin `index()` suited for the job.

It's a very fast substring search function ( implements the Boyer-Moore algorithm ).

Just check its documentation with `perldoc -f index`.

Comment: Does it let you give the searcher hint/condition that the substring can only start a fresh word, so it need not search from middle of string.

Comment: I have roughly million queries to search against roughly 9k substrings..so this optimization should go a long way.

Comment: @p2pnode: Your question doesn't contain this crucial information!

Comment: Well, you can't impose _anchors_ on `index()` like you do with regexes. It could match in the middle of a word. Maybe you have to craft a proper regex as jamessan pointed out.

Comment: @p2pnode: What makes you think that looking for the start of words is faster than looking for the strings?  How long are your words?  What is the start of a word anyway?

Answer (score 2):

I would make a hash with the key being the first word of the 9000 substrings and the value an array with all substrings with that first word.  If many strings contain the same first word, you could use the first two words.

Then for each query, for each word, I would see if that word is in the hash, and then need to match only those strings in the hash's array, starting at that point in the string using the index function.

Assuming that matching is sparse, this would be pretty efficient.  One hash lookup per word and minimal searching for potential matches.

As I write this it reminds me of an Aho-Corasick search.  (See Algorithm::AhoCorasick in CPAN.)  I've never used the module, but the algorithm spends a lot of time building a finite state machine out of the search keys so finding a match is super efficient. I don't know if the CPAN implementation handles word boundaries issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach:

```
# init
my $re = join"|", map quotemeta, sort @substrings;
$re = qr/\b(?:$re)/;

# usage
while (<>) {
  found($1) if /($re)/;
}
```

where `found` is action what you want to do if substring found.

Comment: That is what p2pnode calls 'exhaustive search'.

Comment: @reinierpost: are you sure? Did you done any measurement or just guest? may be using Algorithm::AhoCorasick would be better but I would not say unless made some serious benchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

The builtin `index` function is the fastest general purpose way to check if a string contains a substring.

```
my $find = 'abc';

my $str = '123 abc xyz';

if (index($str, $find) != -1) {
    # process matching $str here
}
```

If `index` still is not fast enough, and you know where in the string your substring might be, you can narrow down on it using `substr` and then use `eq` for the actual comparison:

```
my $find = 'abc';

my $str = '123 abc xyz';

if (substr($str, 4, 3) eq $find) {
    # process matching $str here
}
```

You are not going to get faster than that in Perl without dropping down to C.

Comment: There are several things wrong with this answer: 1) this doesn't tell you how to do this on many different strings 2) this is probably what p2pnode means by exhaustive search, although it really isn't  3) you *can* actually get faster in Perl (e.g. using `study` or other techniques mentioned in the documentation).

Comment: @reinierpost => 1) no example data was given, lacking that, a base case was provided.  The user can easily adapt this to a loop for multiple strings. 2) I have no idea what that means but I cant see how it justifies downvoting a quotestion.  3) regex will never be faster than index or substr/eq, even if the string has been studied.  And presumably if the user is checking strings in a loop, studying each one will be slower than just running the regex.  So in summary, there are several things wrong with your comment, but thanks for playing.